# I have a current PR in a directory. How do I create a separate PR for a different subdirectory within that directory?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I currently have `src/main/java` in a PR that is in a feature branch `Feature_A` and it has all files (using `git add`) that are updated under `src/main/java` and this branch hasn't been merged to master yet. Now I have a set of uncommitted files under `src/main/python`. My question is how to create a PR for these files without adding commits from `Feature_A`.

I've tried to

```
git checkout -b Feature_B
git rebase -i Feature_A
git add src/main/java
git push origin Feature_B
```

but then looking at the PR, it still has all commits from `Feature_A`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Stash your changes:

   ```
   git stash
   ```
2. Switch back to your base branch (`master` in you case)

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
3. Update it:

   ```
   git pull
   ```
4. Create the `Feature_B`:

   ```
   git checkout -b Feature_B
   ```
5. Unstash the changes you want to commit (previously stashed):

   ```
   git stash pop
   ```
6. Stage and commit your changes:

   ```
   git add . && git commit
   ```
7. Push your changes.

   ```
   git push
   ```

Go to your git repository hosting client, and you will able to create a `PR` with only the changes (`commits`) between the `Feature_B` and your `master` branch.